# How to "comment out" annotation entries in Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Given the following property with PHPDoc comment containing an annotation for Doctrine:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;
```

What is the best way to "comment out" one of the annotation lines? e.g. something like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * //Comment out please// @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;
```

Is there a supported way, or a general convention for doing this?

Comment: that's another reason why comments should be comments.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree, although assuming the decision is made for one reason or another to use annotations, it would be nice to mitigate this limitation.

Comment: will // work for annotations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually add the `@foo` annotation (this class will not issue any problem) in order to comment out inside of dockblocks. You can register a global annotation for ignore:

```
AnnotationReader::addGlobalIgnoredName('foo');
```

This will be applied as:

```
/**
 * @Column(type="string", nullable=false, name="body")
 * @foo type="string", nullable=false, name="body2" 
 */
protected $body;
```

You can verify it at [doctrine 2.1 documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-common/en/latest/reference/annotations.html):

> The @Foo annotation. It is not a documentation annotation and not blacklisted. For Doctrine Annotations it is not entirely clear how to handle this annotation. Depending on the configuration an exception (unknown annotation) will be thrown when parsing this annotation

According to quote below, the example should not throws any exception because the `@foo` annotation was registed previously

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I forgot to mention that I'm using the Symfony 2 framework, is it possible to make it work there also?

Comment: Glad to help you! ...I never has used Symphony, but I think It should works, because this snipped is usable for Doctrine models

Answer (score 17):

Just remove the @ for Annotation recognition.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;
```

Answer (score 5):

Just replace the `@` with a `#`

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * #ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
```

Comment: I like this solution the most because it clearly states the intent. When you for example place a space after the `@`, it could be interpreted as a spelling mistake and not a commented out property. The `#` sign is commonly used as a comment sign in multiple languages and thus is better recognised as a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Just put a space between @ and the rest of directive.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
```